# Frontend Category Checkbox

Tags: input

I need help with a code to customize the category taxonomies in the frontend.
It's a code from a plugin:

```
    // Categories
     $vvc_categories     = wp_get_post_terms( $vvc_id, 'vvc_tax_cat', array( "fields" => "ids" ) );

    $out .= '<label for="vvc_categories">' . esc_html__( 'VVC Kategorien', 'vvc_textdomain' ) . '</label>';
    $out .= '<div class="form-input">';

    foreach ( $vvc_post_categories as $key => $value ) {
        $out .= '<input type="checkbox" name="vvc_categories[]" class="vvc_categories" id="vvc_categories" multiple="multiple">';
        $selected = ( is_array( $vvc_categories ) && in_array( $key, $vvc_categories ) ) ? ' selected="selected"' :'';
        $out .= '<option type="checkbox" value="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" ' . $selected . '>' . esc_html( $value ) . '</option>';
    }

    $out .= '</input>';// .vvc_categories
    $out .= '</div>'; // .form-input
```

I changed the type from "select" to "checkbox".
More precisely I changed "select" to "input" and added the "type="checkbox"".

As a result I got the checkboxes but when I hit submit the categories were not saved. All worked fine with the select version.
Maybe someone got a hind for me. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Your select tag doesn't have a name attribute, it only has a type and value. The name is used as an ID when you POST most likely the reason your data isn't saving.

Quick Example:

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
<select name="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo XC90</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab 95</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes SLK</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi TT</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<p>Choose a car, and click the "Submit" button to send input to the server.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

You can run this example here -> [Run Example](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_option_value)

Comment: But I have no select tag. Thats the point. I changed it to an input tag..

And I have a name attribute in the input tag